# How to manage stack in branched quotations?

Tags: factor-lang

If `true` quotation has zero arguments I can use `when` word because implicit `false` quotation also has zero arguments (does nothing).

But when I want to consume argument, I need `else` branch just to clean-up the stack. If logic were more complex, I imagine it might be tedious and error-prone re-factoring. Is there an easier way?

```
: print-if-dir ( directory-entry -- ) dup directory? [ name>> . ] [ drop ] if ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a [`smart-when*`](http://docs.factorcode.org/content/word-smart-when__star__,combinators.smart.html):

```
USE: combinators.smart

: print-if-string ( object -- ) [ string? ] [ . ] smart-when* ;
```

Testing this out in the listener:

```
scratchpad: 2 print-if-string        ! Nothing happens
scratchpad: "2" print-if-string      ! Prints "2"
"2"
```